# Unable to add service reference to Portable library

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library, service-reference

I am not able to add service reference to a portable library. Target frameworks are

.Net 4.5, Windows store and Windows phone 8.

Thanks

Comment: Does your library have same CPU architecture as your solution? I.e. isn't it ARM or x86 specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue that was fixed in [VS 2012 Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188).  So install that and try again.